# iterate through json string

Tags: jquery, json

Need a little help here. I'm new to Coldfusion and I use CF6. I used QueryToArrayOfStructures and jsonencode from CFLib.org to convert my query to array of structs ,and then serialize it to json format.

The result I get looks like this:
[{"lastname":"aaa"},{"lastname":"bbb"},{"lastname":"ccc"}]

What I need to do is get the values of the lastname, ie aaa, bbb, and ccc. I tried to use $.each but could not get it working:

```
$.each(data, function(){
  $.each(this, function(key,value){
    resultHtml+='<div class="result">';
    resultHtml+='<h2><a href="#"> Last name: '+ value +'</a></h2>'; 
    resultHtml+='</div>';
  });
});

$('div#results').html(resultHtml);
```

What I get in the results div would be each of the characters in the data. For example, I would get:

```
[
{
"
l
a
s
t
n
a
m
e
```

... and so on. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you might first need to parse the JSON string with [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). After you have the JSON parsed. you should be able to do $.each() over it.

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/XsMK2/)

Answer (score 1):

What is can see is that the first loop through the array of objects and you dont have to do a second loop.

what you can do is as below

```
var data =  [{"lastname":"aaa"},{"lastname":"bbb"},{"lastname":"ccc"}];
var resultHtml = '';

$.each(data, function(key,value){       
    resultHtml+='<div class="result">';
    resultHtml+='<h2><a href="#"> Last name: '+ value.lastname +'</a></h2>';
    resultHtml+='</div>';
});

$('div#results').html(resultHtml);
```

I hope this helps you!